# How to center subplot titles when using Plotly in Flex Dashboard

Tags: r, plotly, flexdashboard

I'm trying to center the titles of the subplots in my Flex Dashboard. I've tried to change the margin parameter but it doesn't center the titles. I was curious if there was a better way to center the subplot titles (highlighted in the picture below) using plotly

Data:

```
structure(list(date = c("10/1/2019", "11/1/2019", "12/1/2019", 
"1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", "4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", 
"7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "9/1/2020", "10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", 
"12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "2/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", 
"5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "8/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"11/1/2021", "12/1/2021", "1/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "3/1/2022", 
"4/1/2022", "5/1/2022", "6/1/2022", "7/1/2022", "8/1/2022", "9/1/2022", 
"10/1/2022", "11/1/2022", "12/1/2022", "1/1/2023", "2/1/2023", 
"3/1/2023", "4/1/2023", "5/1/2023", "6/1/2023", "7/1/2023", "8/1/2023", 
"10/1/2019", "11/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", 
"3/1/2020", "4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", 
"9/1/2020", "10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", 
"2/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", 
"8/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "11/1/2021", "12/1/2021", 
"1/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "3/1/2022", "4/1/2022", "5/1/2022", "6/1/2022", 
"7/1/2022", "8/1/2022", "9/1/2022", "10/1/2022", "11/1/2022", 
"12/1/2022", "1/1/2023", "2/1/2023", "3/1/2023", "4/1/2023", 
"5/1/2023", "6/1/2023", "7/1/2023", "8/1/2023", "10/1/2019", 
"11/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", 
"4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "9/1/2020", 
"10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "2/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "8/1/2021", 
"9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "11/1/2021", "12/1/2021", "1/1/2022", 
"2/1/2022", "3/1/2022", "4/1/2022", "5/1/2022", "6/1/2022", "7/1/2022", 
"8/1/2022", "9/1/2022", "10/1/2022", "11/1/2022", "12/1/2022", 
"1/1/2023", "2/1/2023", "3/1/2023", "4/1/2023", "5/1/2023", "6/1/2023", 
"7/1/2023", "8/1/2023", "10/1/2019", "11/1/2019", "12/1/2019", 
"1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", "4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", 
"7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "9/1/2020", "10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", 
"12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "2/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", 
"5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "8/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"11/1/2021", "12/1/2021", "1/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "3/1/2022", 
"4/1/2022", "5/1/2022", "6/1/2022", "7/1/2022", "8/1/2022", "9/1/2022", 
"10/1/2022", "11/1/2022", "12/1/2022", "1/1/2023", "2/1/2023", 
"3/1/2023", "4/1/2023", "5/1/2023", "6/1/2023", "7/1/2023", "8/1/2023", 
"10/1/2019", "11/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", 
"3/1/2020", "4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", 
"9/1/2020", "10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", 
"2/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", 
"8/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "11/1/2021", "12/1/2021", 
"1/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "3/1/2022", "4/1/2022", "5/1/2022", "6/1/2022", 
"7/1/2022", "8/1/2022", "9/1/2022", "10/1/2022", "11/1/2022", 
"12/1/2022", "1/1/2023", "2/1/2023", "3/1/2023", "4/1/2023", 
"5/1/2023", "6/1/2023", "7/1/2023", "8/1/2023", "10/1/2019", 
"11/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", 
"4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "9/1/2020", 
"10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "2/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "8/1/2021", 
"9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "11/1/2021", "12/1/2021", "1/1/2022", 
"2/1/2022", "3/1/2022", "4/1/2022", "5/1/2022", "6/1/2022", "7/1/2022", 
"8/1/2022", "9/1/2022", "10/1/2022", "11/1/2022", "12/1/2022", 
"1/1/2023", "2/1/2023", "3/1/2023", "4/1/2023", "5/1/2023", "6/1/2023", 
"7/1/2023", "8/1/2023", "11/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "1/1/2020", 
"2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", "4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", "7/1/2020", 
"8/1/2020", "9/1/2020", "10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", "12/1/2020", 
"1/1/2021", "2/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", 
"7/1/2021", "8/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "11/1/2021", 
"12/1/2021", "1/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "3/1/2022", "4/1/2022", 
"5/1/2022", "6/1/2022", "7/1/2022", "8/1/2022", "9/1/2022", "10/1/2022", 
"11/1/2022", "12/1/2022", "1/1/2023", "2/1/2023", "3/1/2023", 
"4/1/2023", "5/1/2023", "6/1/2023", "7/1/2023", "8/1/2023", "10/1/2019", 
"11/1/2019", "12/1/2019", "1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", 
"4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", "7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "9/1/2020", 
"10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "2/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "8/1/2021", 
"9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "11/1/2021", "12/1/2021", "1/1/2022", 
"2/1/2022", "3/1/2022", "4/1/2022", "5/1/2022", "6/1/2022", "7/1/2022", 
"8/1/2022", "9/1/2022", "10/1/2022", "11/1/2022", "12/1/2022", 
"1/1/2023", "2/1/2023", "3/1/2023", "4/1/2023", "5/1/2023", "6/1/2023", 
"7/1/2023", "8/1/2023", "10/1/2019", "11/1/2019", "12/1/2019", 
"1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020", "4/1/2020", "5/1/2020", "6/1/2020", 
"7/1/2020", "8/1/2020", "9/1/2020", "10/1/2020", "11/1/2020", 
"12/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "2/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "4/1/2021", 
"5/1/2021", "6/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "8/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"11/1/2021", "12/1/2021", "1/1/2022", "2/1/2022", "3/1/2022", 
"4/1/2022", "5/1/2022", "6/1/2022", "7/1/2022", "8/1/2022", "9/1/2022", 
"10/1/2022", "11/1/2022", "12/1/2022", "1/1/2023", "2/1/2023", 
"3/1/2023", "4/1/2023", "5/1/2023", "6/1/2023", "7/1/2023", "8/1/2023"
), Price = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), Perc_Change = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0.5, -0.666666667, 0, 1, 1, -0.25, 0.333333333, 0, -0.5, 
0, 1, -0.75, 0, 1, 0.5, -0.333333333, 1, -0.5, 1, -0.5, 1, 0, 
-0.25, 0.333333333, -0.25, -0.333333333, 0.5, -0.666666667, 0, 
3, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0, -0.25, -0.333333333, 0, 0.5, -0.333333333, 
-0.5, 1, 0, NA, -0.5, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 2, -0.666666667, 2, -0.666666667, 
2, 0.333333333, -0.25, 0, -0.666666667, 2, -0.666666667, 2, -0.666666667, 
0, 3, -0.25, -0.333333333, 0.5, -0.666666667, 3, -0.5, 1, -0.25, 
-0.666666667, 1, 0, 1, -0.25, 0.333333333, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 3, 
-0.25, -0.666666667, 1, -0.5, 3, -0.25, -0.666666667, NA, -0.666666667, 
1, 1, -0.5, -0.5, 2, 0.333333333, -0.25, 0.333333333, -0.5, 0.5, 
0, -0.333333333, -0.5, 1, 0, -0.5, 3, -0.5, 1, -0.5, 1, 0, -0.75, 
2, 0, 0.333333333, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 2, -0.333333333, 1, -0.75, 
2, -0.333333333, 1, -0.75, 0, 0, 2, 0.333333333, 0, -0.25, 0.333333333, 
-0.75, NA, 3, -0.5, 0.5, -0.333333333, 1, -0.5, -0.5, 3, -0.25, 
-0.666666667, 1, 0.5, 0.333333333, 0, -0.75, 0, 2, -0.666666667, 
1, -0.5, 1, -0.5, 0, 1, 1, -0.25, 0.333333333, -0.75, 2, 0.333333333, 
-0.5, 0.5, 0.333333333, 0, -0.25, 0, -0.333333333, 0.5, 0, -0.333333333, 
0, 1, -0.25, -0.666666667, 2, 0.333333333, NA, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0.333333333, 
-0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 3, -0.5, 1, -0.5, -0.5, 3, -0.25, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
-0.75, 3, -0.75, 1, -0.5, 1, -0.5, 1, 0.5, -0.333333333, -0.5, 
0, 0, 2, -0.666666667, 2, -0.333333333, -0.5, 0, 3, -0.75, 1, 
0, -0.5, 1, 1, -0.75, NA, 0, 0, 1, -0.5, 1, -0.25, -0.666666667, 
3, -0.5, -0.5, 2, -0.666666667, 0, 2, 0, 0, -0.333333333, -0.5, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0.333333333, -0.25, -0.333333333, 1, -0.5, 1, -0.75, 
0, 1, 1, -0.5, 0.5, 0.333333333, -0.5, -0.5, 1, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 3, 0, -0.5, 1, -0.25, 0, -0.666666667, 0, 
1, 1, -0.75, 3, -0.25, 0.333333333, -0.25, -0.666666667, 3, 0, 
-0.25, 0.333333333, -0.75, 0, 2, 0, -0.333333333, 0, 0, -0.5, 
2, -0.333333333, 0.5, 0, 0, -0.333333333, 0.5, -0.666666667, 
1, 1, 0, -0.5, -0.5, 2, -0.333333333, -0.5, 1, NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0.5, 0.333333333, -0.25, 0, -0.666666667, 3, -0.25, 0, -0.666666667, 
0, 1, 0, 0.5, -0.666666667, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.333333333, -0.5, 0, 
0.5, 0, -0.666666667, 1, 1, -0.25, -0.333333333, -0.5, 1, 0.5, 
0, -0.333333333, 0.5, 0, 0.333333333, -0.5, 0, 1, -0.5, 0, 0, 
NA, 2, 0, -0.333333333, 1, 0, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.333333333, -0.5, 
1, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 1, -0.75, 2, 0, -0.666666667, 1, 1, -0.75, 
0, 0, 3, -0.25, -0.666666667, 2, 0.333333333, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 
2, 0, 0.333333333, -0.25, 0.333333333, -0.25, -0.333333333, 0.5, 
-0.333333333, 0, -0.5, 2, 0.333333333), Toy = c("Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", 
"Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy1", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", "Toy2", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", 
"Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3", "Toy3"), Region = c("America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "America", "America", "America", "America", 
"America", "America", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -422L))
```

### Code:

### title: "Example FlexDashboard"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny

```
library(tidyquant)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


example_data <- read.csv("example_data.csv")

example_data <- example_data %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date,
                        tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%m/%d/%Y"))) %>%
  drop_na()




segmentation <- read.csv("segmentation_example.csv")
```

## Global {data-orientation=rows}

### Sidebar_Global {.sidebar}

```
selectInput("Segmentation",
            label = "Segmentation",
            choices = unique(segmentation$Segment),
            selected = "Entertainment")




selectizeInput("Group",
            label = "Group",
            choices = c("Select All", "Deselect All",
                        as.character(unlist(segmentation %>%
                        dplyr::select(Group) %>%
                        dplyr::arrange(Group) %>%
                        distinct()))), 
            multiple = TRUE,
            options = list(placeholder = 'Make a selection below'))

dateRangeInput(inputId = "date_range",
               label = "Date Range",
               start = Sys.Date() %m+% years(-2),
               end = Sys.Date(),
               format = 'yyyy-mm')

    radioButtons("changeWaterfallGlobal", label = NULL, choices = c("Quarterly", "Monthly"),
                 selected = "Quarterly", inline = TRUE)
```

### Column

```
#Hides initial error messages
tags$style(type="text/css",
  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
  ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)


observe({
if (!is.null(input$Segmentation)){
  updateSelectInput(
    inputId = "Group",
    choices =c("Select All", "Deselect All",segmentation %>%
      dplyr::filter(Segment == input$Segmentation) %>%
      dplyr::select(Group) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>%
      dplyr::pull(Group) %>%
      str_sort),
    selected = segmentation %>%
      dplyr::filter(Segment == input$Segmentation) %>%
      dplyr::select(Group) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>% slice_head()
    )
  }
})


observe ({
  if("Select All" %in% input$Group){
    updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "Group",
    selected = segmentation %>%
      dplyr::filter(Segment == input$Segmentation) %>%
      dplyr::select(Group) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>%
      dplyr::pull(Group) %>%
      str_sort
    )
  }
  else if("Deselect All"  %in% input$Group){
    updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "Group",
      choices = c("Select All", "Deselect All",segmentation %>%
      dplyr::filter(Segment == input$Segmentation) %>%
      dplyr::select(Group) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>%
      dplyr::pull(Group) %>%
      str_sort),
    selected = ""
    )
  }

})


percent <- function(x, digits = 2, format = "f", ...) {
  paste0(formatC(x, format = format, digits = digits, ...), "%")
}



segment_filt <- reactive({
      if(length(input$Group) >= 0) {
        segment_filt <- NULL
        for(i in input$Group) {
          subset_seg <- segmentation %>%
            dplyr::filter(Group == i)
          segment_filt <- rbind(segment_filt, subset_seg)
        }
      }
      segment_filt
})

    prod_global <- reactive({
      prod_global <- segment_filt() %>%
        dplyr::distinct() %>%
        inner_join(example_data,by = c("Product" = "Toy")) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(Toys = paste(Product, Region
                                        , sep = ' ')) %>%
        dplyr::filter(date >= as.Date(cut(input$date_range[1], "month"))) %>%
        #start date
        dplyr::filter(date <= as.Date(cut(input$date_range[2], "month")))
        #end date
    })
    
    chart_height_regional <- reactive({prod_global() %>%
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(date)) %>%
        dplyr::select(Toys, Region) %>%
        unique %>%
        nrow * 320})
  
    output$plot_global <- renderPlotly({
      shinyjs::show("changePlot")
    if(input$changeWaterfallGlobal == "Monthly"){
      my_plot <- . %>%  plot_ly(
        x = ~ date[1],
        y = 0,
        type = "bar",
        name = "increasing",
        color = I("red"),
        legendgroup = "increasing",
        showlegend = ~ all(showlegend),
        height = chart_height_regional()) %>%
        add_trace(
          x = ~ date[1],
          y = 0,
          type = "bar",
          name = "decreasing",
          color = I("darkgreen"),
          legendgroup = "decreasing",
          showlegend = ~ all(showlegend)
          ) %>%
        add_trace(
          x = ~ date,
          y = ~ Perc_Change,
          type = "waterfall",
          hoverinfo = "text",
          hovertext = ~ paste("Date :", date,
                              "<br> % Change:", percent(Perc_Change),
                              "<br> PRICE:", paste0("$",round(Price, digits = 2))),
          increasing = list(marker = list(color = "red")),
          decreasing = list(marker = list(color = "green")),
          totals = list(marker = list(color = "blue")),
          textposition = "outside",
          legendgroup = ~ legendgroup,
          showlegend = FALSE) %>%
        add_annotations(
          text = ~ unique(Toys),
          x = 0.5,
          y = 1,
          yref = "paper",
          xref = "paper",
          xanchor = "middle",
          yanchor = "center",
          align = "center",
          showarrow = FALSE,
          font = list(size = 12), 
          yshift = 15) %>% 
        layout(yaxis = list(title = "% Change", ticksuffix = "%"),
               xaxis = list(title = c("Date"), 
                            list(tickfont = list(size = 11))),
               legend = list(
                 itemclick = FALSE,
                 itemdoubleclick = FALSE,
                 groupclick = FALSE))

      prod_global()  %>%
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(date)) %>%
        mutate(legendgroup = case_when(
          Perc_Change >= 0 ~ "increasing",
          Perc_Change < 0 ~ "decreasing")) %>%
        distinct() %>% 
        mutate(showlegend = data.table::rleid(Toys, legendgroup) %in% c(1, 2)) %>%
        group_by(Toys, Region)  %>%
        do(p = my_plot(.)) %>%
        subplot(nrows = 3, shareX = FALSE, titleY= TRUE, titleX= FALSE,  margin = 0.07) %>%
        style(showlegend = TRUE, traces = c(1,2))
    } else{
        my_plot <- . %>%  plot_ly(
        x = ~ Quarter[1],
        y = 0,
        type = "bar",
        name = "increasing",
        color = I("red"),
        legendgroup = "increasing",
        showlegend = ~ all(showlegend),
        height = chart_height_regional()) %>%
        add_trace(
          x = ~ Quarter[1],
          y = 0,
          type = "bar",
          name = "decreasing",
          color = I("darkgreen"),
          legendgroup = "decreasing",
          showlegend = ~ all(showlegend)
          ) %>%
        add_trace(
          x = ~ Quarter,
          y = ~ Perc_Change,
          type = "waterfall",
          hoverinfo = "text",
          hovertext = ~ paste("Date :", Quarter,
                              "<br> % Change:", percent(Perc_Change),
                              "<br> Price:", paste0("$",round(Price, digits = 2))),
          increasing = list(marker = list(color = "red")),
          decreasing = list(marker = list(color = "green")),
          totals = list(marker = list(color = "blue")),
          textposition = "outside",
          legendgroup = ~ legendgroup,
          showlegend = FALSE) %>%
        add_annotations(
          text = ~ unique(Toys),
          x = 0.5,
          y = 1,
          yref = "paper",
          xref = "paper",
          xanchor = "middle",
          yanchor = "center",
          align = "center",
          showarrow = FALSE,
          font = list(size = 12), 
          yshift = 16) %>% 
        layout(yaxis = list(title = "% Change", ticksuffix = "%"),
               xaxis = list(title = c("Date"), 
                            list(tickfont = list(size = 7)),
                            tickangle = 45),
               legend = list(
                 itemclick = FALSE,
                 itemdoubleclick = FALSE,
                 groupclick = FALSE))

      prod_global()  %>%
        mutate(Quarter = zoo::as.yearqtr(date)) %>% 
        drop_na() %>%
        group_by(Toys, Region, Quarter) %>% 
        summarise(Price = mean(Price, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
        mutate(Perc_Change = (Price/lag(Price) - 1) * 100, 
               Quarter = as.character(Quarter)) %>%
        mutate(legendgroup = case_when(
          Perc_Change >= 0 ~ "increasing",
          Perc_Change < 0 ~ "decreasing")) %>%
        distinct() %>% 
        drop_na() %>%
        mutate(showlegend = data.table::rleid(Toys, legendgroup) %in% c(1, 2)) %>%
        group_by(Toys, Region)  %>%
        do(p = my_plot(.)) %>%
        subplot(nrows = 3, shareX = FALSE, titleY= TRUE, titleX= FALSE,  margin = 0.07) %>%
        style(showlegend = TRUE, traces = c(1,2))
      
    }
        
     })
    #Renders the plot above with the proper height
    renderUI({
      plotlyOutput("plot_global", height = "100%")
    })
```

[image]

Comment: If you add the plot titles via `annotation` after you create the subplot, e.g. `subplot(...) %>% add_annotations(text = ..., x = c(3/24, 1/2, 21/24), y = 1, xanchor = "middle", showarrow = F, xref = "paper", yref = "paper")` you should be able to get the alignment you're looking for.